# warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    double total;
    char grade;
}student;

void Highest(student record[]);

int main()
{
    int i;
    student record[] = {{1234, "Safiya", 99.5, 'U'},
    {1235, "Tahir", 94.6,'U'},
    {1246, "Ay", 83.2,'U'},
    {1564, "Ju", 40.2, 'U'},
    };

    for(i =0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if (record[i].total>80){
            record[i].grade = 'A';
        }
        else
            if(record[i].total>=50 && record[i].total<= 80){
            record[i].grade = 'B';
            }
        else
            if(record[i].total<50){
            record[i].grade = 'C';
            }

    printf("\nRecord of Student %d:\n", i+1);
    printf("ID: %d\t\tName: %s\t\tTotal: %.2f\t\tGrade: %c\n",
        record[i].id, record[i].name, record[i].total, record[i].grade);
    }

    Highest(record);

    return 0;
}

void Highest(student record[]){

    double highest;
    char  highName;

    highest = record[0].total;

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){

       if(record[i].total>record[0].total)
       {
        highest = record[i].total;
        highName = record[i].name;
       }
    }

    printf("\n\nThe Highest graded student is %s and their grade is %.2f\n", 
        highName, highest);
}
```

When I tried compiling this code, I get -

> "The Highest graded student is (null) and their grade is 99.50", the %s in the function to be as (null)

and the error:

> "warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’".

How can I change that?

I tried to do as they suggested by changing `char` to `char *`, I get a number in the console.

Comment: What is unclear with the error message? Find the line where there is used printf and check function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a `char` to save a string or a pointer to it. You need a pointer for that.

Change `char  highName;` to `char  *highName = record[0].name;`. Now it will store a pointer to the `name` field of the struct. You also have to initialize it, like in the example.

complete code: https://godbolt.org/z/5Yov69E6n

Comment: Just a note - `char` gets promoted to `int` when used in an untyped parameter list such as in `printf`.